how to properly assess correlation in my data
I have a dataset that contains football events. It provides the following info:

event type (on target, off target, goal)
event sub-type (header, distance shot...)
player's name
player's height (in cm)

I am trying to answer the question "do tall football players score more headers"? I am unsure exactly how I should do my correlation analysis. Data is unevenly distributed (there aren't many goals for players taller than 200cm, but there aren't many players that tall either).
Should I compare:

the number of goals scored vs the number of players that exist for a given height (e.g. for 170cm, 180cm, 190cm)?
the goal/attempts ratio with a football player's height (e.g. g/a ratio for 170cm, 180cm, 190cm)?
anything else?

What I have tried:
If I compare the total goals scored per player (s1) with each player's height (s2), I have a low correlation (0.2). IMO this is not the right approach.
If I compare the number of players of a given height (s1) with the number of goals for that same height (s2), I then get a r = 0.98, which looks off too.
I'd love to have suggestions from knowledgeable people in statistics / data science on this one.
I was also thinking, in case of correlation, about doing a p-value test / shuffling players in groups to see if this was just a one time thing due to some tall and extraordinary players.
